# Unable to append in an existing .txt file

Tags: java, android

I'm unable to append in existing .txt file as it overwrites the older data written in the file. Please help me out by telling me where am I getting wrong.

This is the a class file(Orderact.java) which is related to file handling.

```
     String data="\nName- " + partyn + "; ndate- " + dt + "; product- " + prosel + "; qty- " + qty + ";";
                    // Create the folder if required.
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fb");
                    if(!f.exists()) {
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fb";
                        File folder = new File(path);
                        folder.mkdirs();
                    }
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fb";
                    File folder = new File(path);
                    File file = new File(folder, "testing.txt");
                    try {
                        if(!file.exists()) {
                            // Create the file.
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                            myOutWriter.append(data);
                            myOutWriter.close();
                            fOut.flush();
                            fOut.close();
                            Toast.makeText(Orderact.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                            myOutWriter.append(data);
                            myOutWriter.close();
                            fOut.close();
                            Toast.makeText(Orderact.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Orderact.this, "Something went wrong.\n Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
                    }
```

Comment: `FileOutputStream` -> read the doc for that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open your file in `apppend` mode, as follows

Change

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

to

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Please refer to [FileOutputStream javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File))